# What is the equivalent of BinaryWriter.Write() from C# in Python?

Tags: python, c#, binarywriter, unsigned-long-long-int

So I have this function in a C# program:

```
public void Write(BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(0x6369676F6C6572uL | ((ulong)Type << 56));
        writer.Write(Revision);
        writer.Write((ulong)(int)((uint)IsFavorite.ToInt() & 1u));
    }
```

I would like to translate it to Python but I'm not sure how, I found a package for python called [binstream](https://pypi.org/project/binstream/) but I'm not sure how am I supposed to translate stuff like `0x6369676F6C6572uL` to Python.

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found this https://pypi.org/project/binstream/ it claims to be compatible with BinaryReader and BinaryWriter